# Phpword data not show in the chart

Tags: php, phpword

this my sample code of phpword to make chart in microsoft word

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter;
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$categories = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$series1 = array(5, 3, 4, 2, 7);

$chart = $section->addChart('column', $categories, $series1);
$chart->getStyle()->setWidth(Converter::inchToEmu(2.5))->setHeight(Converter::inchToEmu(2));

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

when the code run and save to the microsoft word the data declare by the variable not show in the chart.

[Click this to see the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmBGe.jpg)

Comment: I'm wondering how the `new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord()` is even working

Comment: According to the [PHPWord documentation](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#basic-example) it seems to be the correct way, but I also don't know about PHPWord.

Comment: I just tested, your example and https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/c71069022e07d768ec69a5e43e3b6f1fa4a95e84/samples/Sample_32_Chart.php and opened it in LibreOffice and it seems to not work, all charts are empty.